# Limitting Rows For Doctrine FindAll Method

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

i am trying to limit rows which return from doctrine's FindAll method.

```
public function getActiveUsersByPoint($limit = 100){
    $users = $this->userRepository->findAll();

    return $users;
}
```

This code work but i can't use $limit variable for limitting results. How can i done this ?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The EntityRepository#findBy() method additionally accepts orderings, limit and offset as second to fourth parameters:

```
$tenUsers = $em->getRepository('MyProject\Domain\User')
               ->findBy(
                   array('age' => 20),        // $where 
                   array('name' => 'ASC'),    // $orderBy
                   10,                        // $limit
                   0                          // $offset
                 );
```

Answer (score 9):

In order to find all results, you should pass an empty array to the findBy method, I think it is what you pretend:

```
$users= $em->userRepository->findBy(
            array(),
            array('id' => 'DESC'),
            10,
            0
        );
```

First param is an empty array, which it is equivalent to findAll(), then the order (I put id as sample), then the **limit** and finally the offset.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is for Doctrine 1.x, FindAll means "find all". To limit the results, use DQL:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('UserRepository')
  ->limit($limit);
$users = $q->execute();
```

Comment: this is doctrine 1.x  ... my answer is 2.x